# Transfer Specific Data from one Worksheet to another for Reports

Tags: excel, formula

I have One Excel Sheets to manage my customer's orders. below please find the picture for the same.

[image]

Right now, to plan my production for the material, I am manually copying and pasting data whose orders are "To Ship in Plan". to report sheet as per below image.

[image]

Can someone advise me on a specific VBA code or formula to arrange data automatically into report sheet which are "To Ship in Plan"?

Comment: Please try not to use pictures, on many devices, such as my PC, they are unreadable.

It would be better if you quoted their text in your question. This would also help anyone who wants to reporduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily a StackOverflow question IMHO, it is rather a "how do I learn VBA" question - as you are not asking about a concrete problem you need a solution for. Regardless, I wrote a bit of code that should do what you described in your post.

Please note, that it does basically 0 error checks and that the execution of Macro codes is irreversible, so please store back-up files of your data before you get started:

```
Sub ShipInPlan()
        Dim OrderNum As Long
        Dim StartNum, EndNum As Long
        Dim NumFound As Boolean
        Dim Ws As Worksheet

        'Create input box, so you the user can design which number to ship
        OrderNum = InputBox("For which order Number do you want to create the report?")

        'Find first row of order
        NumFound = False
        Counter = 1

        Do While NumFound = False
            If Sheets("Booking").Cells(Counter, 1).Value <> OrderNum Then
                Counter = Counter + 1
            Else
                NumFound = True
            End If

            If Counter > 500 Then
                NumFound = True
            End If
        Loop

        StartNum = Counter

        'Find last row of order
        Counter = Counter + 1
        NumFound = False

        Do While NumFound = False
            If Len(Sheets("Booking").Cells(Counter, 1).Value) = 0 Then
                Counter = Counter + 1
            Else
                NumFound = True
            End If

            If Counter - NumFound > 500 Then
                NumFound = True
            End If
        Loop

        EndNum = Counter - 2

        'Delete any report sheet that exists then create Sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets("Report").Delete
        Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
                 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        Ws.Name = "Report"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Copy contents and go to report sheet
        Sheets("Report").Range("A1:I1").Value = Sheets("Booking").Range("A1:I1").Value
        Sheets("Report").Range(Sheets("Report").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Report").Cells(1 + EndNum - StartNum, 10)) = Sheets("Booking").Range(Sheets("Booking").Cells(StartNum, 1), Sheets("Booking").Cells(EndNum, 10)).Value
        Sheets("Report").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. i require all orders list  which are "To Ship In Plan". ( from H Column ). from current code i am only getting data for specific customer.

Comment: You do understand that this is not a platform where people write you turnkey code. If you know some level of VBA, you should be able to adjust the range of copying from this sample code onwards. If you found the code helpful, please upvote the solution.